# Dog is crying and barking every morning since we moved in a new house

Tags: dogs, sleep

We recently moved from a condo to a newly built house. Ever since we moved in, our dog (10 months female spanador) wakes up in her cage every morning between 6h30 and 7h00 and cries, and even barks very loudly, until we go down and let her out of her cage. At our condo she always kept quiet until there was some movement, which sometimes meant until 8h30 or 9h00.

Her cage is located in the basement and our bedroom is on the second floor. At first, I thought it was because we didn't have any curtains on our basement windows, and the early light woke her up, but since then we blocked them all, so there's really no daylight getting in the basement, and it didn't really change anything in her behavior. So I'm assuming she's feeling insecure not to feel us nearby.

We're using the same cage we had at the condo, and put in the same blankets she always had with her in the cage. I tried putting in some of her toys too, but to no avail.

What can we do to make her stop crying and barking? Moving the cage to a different floor is not a solution we'd like to go for.

Comment: Are you ever awake before she wakes up? If so, are there any noise that she may find unusual? Like the mail persons used to drive by the condo at 8:30 and they now drive by the house at 6:30.  I am assuming your move is in the same general area.

Comment: The dog wakes us up with her crying. We moved in the same general area, yes, but I cannot tell if there are any noises that would feel very different to her. New houses are being built on our street, so the construction noises might wake her up, I hadn't consider this. But this waking phenomenon happens during the weekend too, while there are no construction going on.

Comment: Hopefully one of a dog experts can help you, [here is a slightly related question.](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/can-rabbits-tell-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We eventually opted to let her loose in the house during the night, with a large cushion in our bedroom on which she now sleeps every night, and since she stopped crying. However, we never found out why she had this behavior at first when her cage was in the basement.